# Should you use another navigation controller for bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to android compose I wanted to ask is it a good practice to define two navigation controllers and graphs for bottom navigation and general screen navigation(like new screen on button click) or should I use only one graph and controller?

I have a working bottom navigation should I expand on it

Comment: You should use one, with nested graphs if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't want more than one NavController in your app instead you should nested graphs so you could have nested navigation in your app.

- If you are the type of person that likes documentation here is how to
  make a [bottom navigation bar the right way](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav)
- If you are the type of person that likes tutorials here is a well
  explained [tutorial by Stevzda-san](https://youtu.be/gNzPGI9goU0)

Comment: thanks very much!!..really appriciated

Comment: @ArchitAnant can you mark it a correct answer so that anyone having the same problem could find it easily